# Student Loan Cancellation re: WV vs EPA

Tags: united-states, us-supreme-court

The recent WV vs. EPA ruling limits federal agencies ability to exceed the power specifically granted to them in cases where it could be considered an “extraordinary case” of “political and economic significance,” where an agency makes “unheralded” use of its authority.  If that's the case, then the agency must be able to point to a “clear statement” from Congress authorizing its action.

Given the initial intent of the HEROES Act, it's hard to see how there would be such a "clear statement" permitting the cancellation of student debt for several million people with no connection to the military, nor in a time of war.  It also seems a stretch at this point to consider us in a state of "national emergency" over the covid pandemic.

Could such a lack of specificity prevent the Biden Administration from using the HEROES Act to cancel student debt across such a broad range of people?

Comment: A press briefing is not a legally-implementable executive order, and no such order exists. When it does, it would be possible to look at the legal rationale and compare it to statutory language and case law. Until there is a concrete statement of authority, we can only make stuff us. A better way to frame the question is something along the lines of "What is the most bullet-proof order that relies on the HEROES Act"?

Comment: I get that, but other announced details have indicated they plan to use the HEROES Act as their source of authority, which seemed like a stretch to me, so I thought I'd ask.

Comment: I think the question of standing to assert that argument is logically prior and probably renders the question non-justiciable.

Comment: @ohwilleke  I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean in your comment.  Would you mind elaborating a bit more?

Comment: @mikem See https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/83639/would-anyone-have-standing-to-challenge-bidens-student-loan-forgiveness-program

Comment: So, if I understand what you're saying, SCOTUS made a ruling against the EPA and regulatory overreach in general, but left no way for a party affected by regulatory overreach to have standing to sue to correct it?  The federal government is represented and funded by the people and by the states.  If neither the people, nor the states (ie governors, senators, etc.) have standing, and the full house of congress is practically never on the same page, how would regulatory overreach ever be held to the "major questions doctrine"?  If an agency is acting outside its bounds, aren't we all "injured"?