# Would anyone have standing to challenge Biden's student loan forgiveness program?

Tags: united-states, standing

Assuming that President Biden does sign an Executive Order to forgive student loans, would anyone have standing to challenge this action in court? Presumably those whose debt was discharged won't have standing because they didn't suffer any damages but how about Congress or some other government institution?

Comment: In case you didn't catch it, [this Virginia Law Review article](https://www.virginialawreview.org/articles/standing-and-student-loan-cancellation/) that I linked in [my answer to your previous question](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/83637/5104) is all about this.  Their answer is that this question lies in a "standing dead zone":  "it is likely that no party would have standing to challenge the executive action."

Comment: I wonder, what would have happened if Biden did not set limits (so, instead of just people earning less than $125k getting a $10k debt cut, people earning millions could get even more than $100k)?  It's hard to believe that there is no check on executive orders beyond just protests (and fear of losing the next election).

Answer (score 3):

Not less than a full house of Congress, and perhaps Congress as a whole, might have standing. It is hard to see anyone else who would. The [law of Congressional standing](https://crsreports.congress.gov/product/pdf/R/R45636) (the link is to a report of the Congressional Research Service, a policy research arm of the Library of Congress that does research for Congress) is quite involved and is not perfectly consistent and clear. Congress would argue that it has suffered an institutional injury as an institution and perhaps authorize someone to bring suit on its behalf via a joint resolution.

> As the Court explained in *Arizona State Legislature*, an
> “institutional injury” is an injury that “scarcely zeroe[s] in on any
> individual member,” but rather “impact[s] all Members of Congress and
> both Houses . . . equally.”

There is considerable uncertainty regarding how this would be applied which is not really at issue in this case at the present time since Democrats control both houses of Congress and support the President in this policy.

Individuals legislators lack standing to sue in a case like this one.

*See also* Tara Leigh Grove & Neal Devins, "Congress’s (Limited) Power to Represent Itself in Court", 99 Cornell L. Rev. 571 (2014); Matthew L. Hall, "Standing of Intervenor-Defendants in Public Law Litigation", 80 Fordham L. Rev. 1539 (2012).

A blog entry from a law professor [considers the question](https://reason.com/volokh/2022/09/05/does-anyone-have-standing-to-bring-a-lawsuit-against-bidens-student-loan-debt-cancellation-policy/) and comes up with the Congressional standing analysis above, the notion that a loan serving company paid on the dollar value of the loans serviced might have standing (which isn't inconceivable but is a stretch), and finally considers "competitor standing", a minority view that I do not think is sound in these circumstances (because the forgiveness is retroactive only and does not change competitive positions going forward).

Comment: Would the lawsuit in this case be "Congress v. Biden"? "Congress v. President"? Presumably not "United States v. United States"

Comment: @Someone *See, e.g.*, *U.S. House of Representatives v. Burwell*, 130 F. Supp. 3d 53 (D.D.C. 2015); *U.S. House of Representatives v. Mnuchin*, 379 F. Supp. 3d 8 (D.D.C. 2019); *Arizona State Legislature v. Arizona Independent
Redistricting Commission*, 135 S. Ct. 2652 (2015); *Virginia House of Delegates v. Bethune-Hill*, 139 S. Ct. 1945 (2019). Not all finding standing present. Custom is to sue the lowest federal official with authority to grant relief not the President unless no other person could act. Here probably the person who signs the forgiveness documents in the Dept. of Education.

Comment: Couldn't every individual who has not been given relief make a legitimate claim of having suffered damages?

Comment: @MichaelHall What damages? “I didn’t get money there’s no argument I qualify for” aren’t damages.

Comment: @MichaelHall No. The fact that someone else gets a benefit that you do not is not an "injury in fact" that suffices to establish standing to sue.

Comment: Yes, I can see that those who haven't benefitted aren't "damaged", but surely there is some principal of law that says if the government uses public money for some cause that it must be used equitably?

Comment: "The fact that someone else gets a benefit that you do not is not an "injury in fact" that suffices to establish standing to sue." IANAL, but I'm rather sure that there are circumstances where it can, such as it being arbitrary and capricious or discriminatory. If Biden were to sign an executive order declaring that all the debt of black people is canceled, surely white people with debt would have standing to sue.

Comment: @Acccumulation Nope. Almost certainly not, assuming the debt was owed purely to the federal government. Standing law in the U.S. makes it very hard to review taxing and spending decisions of the government even when there is clear evidence of unconstitutionality. The main barrier to the legislation you describe is political and the self-regulation of the federal government by its internal lawyers. Many countries have a process for this kind of judicial review of spending constitutionality, but the U.S. does not, and specifically disavows taxpayer standing.

Comment: @MichaelHall "But surely there is some principal of law that says if the government uses public money for some cause that it must be used equitably?" There is absolutely not any such principle.

Comment: I understand the arguments, but it sure feels arbitrary, capricious, and discriminatory.  Is there such a thing as temporal or categorical discrimination?  i.e. "During this election year I hereby relieve this select group of one particular type of debt"?

Comment: @MichaelHall "Is there such a thing as temporal or categorical discrimination?" No.

Comment: Ok, well then... let's see in the Fall if this political stunt works or backfires.

Comment: @MichaelHall,Accumulation See [this Virginia Law Review](https://www.virginialawreview.org/articles/standing-and-student-loan-cancellation/) article for further reasons why "taxpayers" and "former borrowers" wouldn't have standing.

Comment: Would you like to update your answer now that Biden's lost in court?

Comment: @JonathanReez At some point I may go back and look up the case and figure out what happened procedurally. I certainly don't claim that the law is so predictable that anyone get correctly determine the outcome of a legal issue 100% of the time and do my best using what I know at the time. I don't pro-actively review old answers, but if I have time I'll see what happened. Any way you could link the final court ruling on the merits to simplify the analysis? IIRC some state government agency that got fees from administering the program was the successful plaintiff. I didn't know it existed.